# what kind of signal have to be caught when shell exits

Tags: python

I have a python program which needs to clean up something when the shell exits unexpectly, what kind of signal have to be caught?

Comment: yes....the problem is sometimes, the shell connection will be unstable, which will shutdown the program, but I have to do something cleanup...

Comment: Rob's comment under his answer is right then, catching `SIGHUP` should work in your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) module to add a handler for a specific signal. For example SIGINT and SIGTERM:

```
import signal
def handler(signum, frame):
    print('Caught signal %d' % signum)
    # Now do something (clean-up?) ...
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)

input() # Example to keep the program running
```

Comment: it seems that these two signals couldn't be caught when I shutdown the terminal, you could try by write to a file in the handler and you will see that terminating the terminal won't write anything to the file.

Comment: @ZhenyuLi Listen to SIGHUP. For an overview of signals, see [`man 7 signal`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+7).